# How can I find the common quadratic factor of multiple polynomials?

Tags: factoring

$x^4-13x^2+36$,
$2x^3+3x^2-11x-6$,
$3x^3+x^2-20x+12$
Find a common quadratic factor of these expressions.
Help?

Comment: is your second equation reelly $$2x^2+x^2-11x-6$$?

Comment: As it is written currently, one of your polynomials is a quadratic polynomial, so it must be a factor of both of the others if they all have a common quadratic factor.

Comment: sorry, typo. corrected now

Comment: Have you tried factoring any of the individual expressions?

Comment: what are the factors of 36?  Can you find a factor pair that sums to 13?

Comment: $x=\pm 2$ is a root of the first. You could factor that, giving $$(x-2)(x+2)(x-3)(x+3)$$ Then see which of these factors goes into the other expressions. **Edit**: None of those factors divide the other polynomials...

Comment: That common factor would also divide every linear combination of those polynomials

Comment: Are you sure you don't still have typos?

Comment: They still have no common quadratic factor.

Comment: Sorry, 1 more type just fixed, definitely correct now.

Comment: Where are you getting these polynomials? You **still** do not have a common quadratic factor.

Comment: Dammit changes didn't save. Also, I got them, it was x=2, -3.

Comment: Can you explain your method tho plz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Letting these polynomials be $p_1(x),p_2(x),p_3(x)$, then any common divisor of $p_2$ and $p_3$ must be a divisor of:

$$3p_2(x)-2p_3(x)=7x^2+7x-42=7(x^2+x-6)$$

Does $x^2+x-6=(x+3)(x-2)$ divide $p_1$, $p_2$, and $p_3$?

Comment: Yes, that is the answer given, thanks, however, how did you get 3p2(x)−2p3(x)

Comment: I wanted to find some combination of the polynomials which had no $x^3$ of $x^4$ term, and the easiest way was to use $p_2,p_3$.

Answer (score 0):

First and second:
 $$  \left(   x^{4}  - 13 x^{2}  + 36 \right)  $$

$$  \left(  2 x^{3}  + 3 x^{2}  - 11 x  - 6 \right)  $$

$$  \mbox{GCD} =   \color{magenta}{  \left(   x^{2}  +  x  - 6 \right) }   $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{4}  - 13 x^{2}  + 36 \right)  \left( \frac{ 4}{21 } \right)  -  \left(  2 x^{3}  + 3 x^{2}  - 11 x  - 6 \right)  \left(   \frac{ 2 x  - 3 }{ 21 }  \right)  =  \left(   -  x^{2}  -  x  + 6 \right)  $$

First and third:
 $$  \left(   x^{4}  - 13 x^{2}  + 36 \right)  $$

$$  \left(  3 x^{3}  +  x^{2}  - 20 x  + 12 \right)  $$ 
 $$  \mbox{GCD} =   \color{magenta}{  \left(   x^{2}  +  x  - 6 \right) }   $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{4}  - 13 x^{2}  + 36 \right)  \left( \frac{ 9}{56 } \right)  -  \left(  3 x^{3}  +  x^{2}  - 20 x  + 12 \right)  \left(   \frac{ 3 x  - 1 }{ 56 }  \right)  =  \left(   -  x^{2}  -  x  + 6 \right)  $$ 
Second and third:
 $$  \left(  2 x^{3}  + 3 x^{2}  - 11 x  - 6 \right)  $$

$$  \left(  3 x^{3}  +  x^{2}  - 20 x  + 12 \right)  $$ 
 $$  \mbox{GCD} =   \color{magenta}{  \left(   x^{2}  +  x  - 6 \right) }   $$ 
 $$  \left(  2 x^{3}  + 3 x^{2}  - 11 x  - 6 \right)  \left( \frac{ 3}{7 } \right)  -  \left(  3 x^{3}  +  x^{2}  - 20 x  + 12 \right)  \left( \frac{ 2}{7 } \right)  =  \left(   x^{2}  +  x  - 6 \right)  $$

======================================================================================

more detail on the Euclidean algorithm

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

$$  \left(   x^{4}  - 13 x^{2}  + 36 \right)  $$

$$  \left(  2 x^{3}  + 3 x^{2}  - 11 x  - 6 \right)  $$

$$  \left(   x^{4}  - 13 x^{2}  + 36 \right)  =  \left(  2 x^{3}  + 3 x^{2}  - 11 x  - 6 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 2 x  - 3 }{ 4 }  \right) } +  \left(   \frac{  - 21 x^{2}  - 21 x  + 126 }{ 4 }  \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(  2 x^{3}  + 3 x^{2}  - 11 x  - 6 \right)  =  \left(   \frac{  - 21 x^{2}  - 21 x  + 126 }{ 4 }  \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  - 8 x  - 4 }{ 21 }  \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 0}{1} $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 1}{0} $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 2 x  - 3 }{ 4 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{ 2 x  - 3 }{ 4 }  \right) }{ \left( 1  \right) } $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  - 8 x  - 4 }{ 21 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{  - 4 x^{2}  + 4 x  + 24 }{ 21 }  \right) }{ \left(   \frac{  - 8 x  - 4 }{ 21 }  \right) } $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{2}  -  x  - 6 \right)  \left( \frac{ 4}{21 } \right)  -  \left(  2 x  + 1 \right)  \left(   \frac{ 2 x  - 3 }{ 21 }  \right)  =  \left( -1  \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{4}  - 13 x^{2}  + 36 \right)  =  \left(   x^{2}  -  x  - 6 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x^{2}  +  x  - 6 \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(  2 x^{3}  + 3 x^{2}  - 11 x  - 6 \right)  =  \left(  2 x  + 1 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x^{2}  +  x  - 6 \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$ 
 $$  \mbox{GCD} =   \color{magenta}{  \left(   x^{2}  +  x  - 6 \right) }   $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{4}  - 13 x^{2}  + 36 \right)  \left( \frac{ 4}{21 } \right)  -  \left(  2 x^{3}  + 3 x^{2}  - 11 x  - 6 \right)  \left(   \frac{ 2 x  - 3 }{ 21 }  \right)  =  \left(   -  x^{2}  -  x  + 6 \right)  $$

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

$$  \left(   x^{4}  - 13 x^{2}  + 36 \right)  $$

$$  \left(  3 x^{3}  +  x^{2}  - 20 x  + 12 \right)  $$

$$  \left(   x^{4}  - 13 x^{2}  + 36 \right)  =  \left(  3 x^{3}  +  x^{2}  - 20 x  + 12 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 3 x  - 1 }{ 9 }  \right) } +  \left(   \frac{  - 56 x^{2}  - 56 x  + 336 }{ 9 }  \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(  3 x^{3}  +  x^{2}  - 20 x  + 12 \right)  =  \left(   \frac{  - 56 x^{2}  - 56 x  + 336 }{ 9 }  \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  - 27 x  + 18 }{ 56 }  \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 0}{1} $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 1}{0} $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 3 x  - 1 }{ 9 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{ 3 x  - 1 }{ 9 }  \right) }{ \left( 1  \right) } $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  - 27 x  + 18 }{ 56 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{  - 9 x^{2}  + 9 x  + 54 }{ 56 }  \right) }{ \left(   \frac{  - 27 x  + 18 }{ 56 }  \right) } $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{2}  -  x  - 6 \right)  \left( \frac{ 9}{56 } \right)  -  \left(  3 x  - 2 \right)  \left(   \frac{ 3 x  - 1 }{ 56 }  \right)  =  \left( -1  \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{4}  - 13 x^{2}  + 36 \right)  =  \left(   x^{2}  -  x  - 6 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x^{2}  +  x  - 6 \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(  3 x^{3}  +  x^{2}  - 20 x  + 12 \right)  =  \left(  3 x  - 2 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x^{2}  +  x  - 6 \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$ 
 $$  \mbox{GCD} =   \color{magenta}{  \left(   x^{2}  +  x  - 6 \right) }   $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{4}  - 13 x^{2}  + 36 \right)  \left( \frac{ 9}{56 } \right)  -  \left(  3 x^{3}  +  x^{2}  - 20 x  + 12 \right)  \left(   \frac{ 3 x  - 1 }{ 56 }  \right)  =  \left(   -  x^{2}  -  x  + 6 \right)  $$

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

$$  \left(  2 x^{3}  + 3 x^{2}  - 11 x  - 6 \right)  $$

$$  \left(  3 x^{3}  +  x^{2}  - 20 x  + 12 \right)  $$

$$  \left(  2 x^{3}  + 3 x^{2}  - 11 x  - 6 \right)  =  \left(  3 x^{3}  +  x^{2}  - 20 x  + 12 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left( \frac{ 2}{3 } \right) } +  \left(   \frac{ 7 x^{2}  + 7 x  - 42 }{ 3 }  \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(  3 x^{3}  +  x^{2}  - 20 x  + 12 \right)  =  \left(   \frac{ 7 x^{2}  + 7 x  - 42 }{ 3 }  \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 9 x  - 6 }{ 7 }  \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 0}{1} $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 1}{0} $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left( \frac{ 2}{3 } \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left( \frac{ 2}{3 } \right) }{ \left( 1  \right) } $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 9 x  - 6 }{ 7 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{ 6 x  + 3 }{ 7 }  \right) }{ \left(   \frac{ 9 x  - 6 }{ 7 }  \right) } $$ 
 $$  \left(  2 x  + 1 \right)  \left( \frac{ 3}{7 } \right)  -  \left(  3 x  - 2 \right)  \left( \frac{ 2}{7 } \right)  =  \left( 1  \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(  2 x^{3}  + 3 x^{2}  - 11 x  - 6 \right)  =  \left(  2 x  + 1 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x^{2}  +  x  - 6 \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(  3 x^{3}  +  x^{2}  - 20 x  + 12 \right)  =  \left(  3 x  - 2 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x^{2}  +  x  - 6 \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$ 
 $$  \mbox{GCD} =   \color{magenta}{  \left(   x^{2}  +  x  - 6 \right) }   $$ 
 $$  \left(  2 x^{3}  + 3 x^{2}  - 11 x  - 6 \right)  \left( \frac{ 3}{7 } \right)  -  \left(  3 x^{3}  +  x^{2}  - 20 x  + 12 \right)  \left( \frac{ 2}{7 } \right)  =  \left(   x^{2}  +  x  - 6 \right)  $$ 
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$

Answer (score 0):

Expounding on what John Doe said in the comments:

Turns out we can factor the first polynomial easily as $$x^4 - 13x^2 + 36 = (x^2-4)(x^2-9)=(x+2)(x-2)(x+3)(x-3)$$

Any quadratic factor of the first polynomial is a product of two of these linear factors. Thus the common quadratic factor has to be a product of two of these linear factors.

These two linear factors will also be factors of the other two polynomials. To check whether each linear factor of the form $(x-a)$ is a factor of a polynomial, we need to plug $a$ into the polynomial and see if we get zero. Since we get zero in both other polynomials when we plug in both $3$ and $-2$, the common quadratic factor is $(x-3)(x+2)$.